# How to Make columns in row

Tags: html, css

Hi i want to know that how can we create column in a row with html and css.
Like this in the picture.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAXvX.png)

Comment: Please provide examples of what you've tried so far and what specific problems you're having. (The current question sounds like you want someone to write the code for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using one row like container, inside create 4 div's and add display flex and justify-content.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Flex Box to have a single row of items and use the boxes to space appropriately, this will also provide scaling for different screen sizes.

Here is a link to a great explaination of what Flex Box can do: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If that's not what you're looking for, there's always making a table.